# Android ListView and Volley

Tags: android, listview, android-volley

Very new to android and volley (double trouble :))

After trying the listview with an array of strings(it worked and I was able to see the result) and volley to retrieve from one of those online test api (it worked and I see the result)

When I attempted to combine the two (the response from volley, parse it and pass it to the adapter) and nothing shows.  Would someone kindly point me to some solid tutorial combining volley and listview or help to show me how to get the adapter to display the response correctly in the listview.

Hope someone out there with time to help.

My Mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.web.listviewexample;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Array of strings...
    String[] mobileArray = {"Android", "Iphone", "Windows", "WebOs", "BlackBerry", "Max OS x"};

    TextView results;
    String JsonURL ="https://reqres.in/api/users/2";
    String data="";

    //define the volley request queue. It handles requests
    RequestQueue requestQueue;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //get the listview that will communicate with the adapter
        ListView listexample = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
        //prepare the adapter
        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        //attach the adapter
        listexample.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Volley stuff --cricket_007 Stackoverflow.com answer
        final JsonObjectRequest obj= new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, JsonURL, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    // parse the response
                    response = response.getJSONObject("data");

                    // add things to the adapter
                    adapter.add(response.toString());
                }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public  void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){error.printStackTrace();
                }

            });

       Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(obj);
        }
    }
```

Activity_Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >


    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout
```

> activity_listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold">

</TextView>
```

getting this error 
[image]

Comment: Your JsonUrl isn't valid. It has a semicolon

Comment: And you have two `Volley.newRequestQueue(this)`, where only one is needed

Comment: @Marco in your code you are creating the Adapter below the Volley request. Volley request is Asynchronous by default so therefore you want to create the Adapter or assign the value in `onResponse`.

Comment: @Enzokie Not necessarily inside, but definitely before

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How to implement a listview using volley android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433395/how-to-implement-a-listview-using-volley-android?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to incorporate the adapter with Volley?

First, I think you need to fix your URL, then you just add to an adapter like an Arraylist

Second, your second parameter to the ArrayAdapter needs to be a layout that contains an ID of `android:id/text1` if you aren't going to provide any additional arguments (it's fine you didn't know that, it buried in the documentation). That being said, there's a built-in layout for a single TextView

```
    //Get the listview 
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
    // make adapter and set it
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Do Volley things 
    final JsonObjectRequest obj= new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, JsonUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                // parse the response 
                response = response.getJSONObject("data");

                // add things to the adapter 
                adapter.add(response.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you both for your time. I'm thankfull cricket_007 to your this line "adapter.add(response.toString())" ...that is the missing part from all those tutorials.  It's been a long 8 hours reading and trying. I'll be back with upvote lol.

Comment: Need your help again.  I added your code (I update the activity_main.java above) and getting error (attached the screen for that error above) ...

Comment: It should work regardless of that warning, but I forgot `ArrayAdapter<String>` on the left side

Comment: cricket_007   ......Your're correct. It worked. Thank you so much. You helped big time. I appreciate it and have a great weekend.